# PHP INSERT INTO MySQL not working, no error given

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to execute an INSERT INTO when a search button is clicked. Eventually I'd like to submit the search term into the database, however I'm currently just trying to submit a simple string to ensure the initial INSERT INTO works correctly, which it currently doesn't.

I have the following:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="search" name="search" id="results" placeholder="Enter search">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="frstBtn" value="searchterm"><br>
</form>

<?php
        $searchterm = "";
    ?>
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tableName (variableName) VALUES ('test')";
            $results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
        }
        ?>
```

The latter php function, search, works perfectly fine, but the former function including the INSERT INTO does not.

[Here is the table itself in phpmyadmin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw1xA.png)

I have successfully manually copied and pasted the actual INSERT INTO statement into the actual database and it has worked fine, so I know the issue isn't with the statement. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Two questions: 1. are you sure the connection to your database, $conn, is successful? 2. is the search query no longer than 30 characters?

Comment: Hey! The $conn is indeed successful, the connect.php is included at the top of the file and displays "connected successfully" when I refresh the page. The search query isn't involved yet at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `searchTerm` column is defined as `PRIMARY`, I’m ready to bet that you are trying to insert the same value twice and you don't have enabled the `error_reporting`. To find out exactly what the problem is, first of all enable all errors by adding the following at the beginning of your script:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Also, note that you must use `mysqli_error($conn)` instead of `mysqli_error()`.

By the way, to *ignore* errors when inserting unique values, use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO searchHistory(searchTerm) VALUES ('test')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Fortunately it seems I've just made a simple error somewhere along the line. The error reporting is stating "No database selected". In the connect.php, I have the following:

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "Liam";
    $password = "Course123Work";
    $dbname = "cwDatabase";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";
    ?>

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting, but as you can see, the username, password and database are all stated correctly in the connect.php, and I also receive the 'connected successfully' echo text on my page.

Comment: Please note that you must specify `$dbname` as fourth argument for `new mysqli`.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much, I think a fresh set of eyes was what I needed after staring at this for so long and missing the simple things. Much appreciated.